# Passing bytes32 to constructor

Tags: contract-deployment, constructor, bytes32, api

I have s constructor that takes a bytes32 parameter and assign its value to the `jobID` variable

```
contract APIConsumer {

    bytes32 public jobId;

    constructor( bytes32 _jobId) {
        jobId = _jobId;
    }
}
```

But when I pass the value `"ec013753fda740f8bc74a966daea0723"` in the constructor it assign this value to the `jobId` variable `"0x00000000000000000000000000000000ec013753fda740f8bc74a966daea0723"`
I want to know why it adds those zeros and how to fix it (make it assign the same value passed in the parameters and do not add zeros).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended behavior, the value is padded right ( = zeroes are added to the left of your number to fill the entire 32 bytes). I don't think you actually want  to "fix" this, but if you do, you could use a byte array instead, like so:

```
bytes public jobId;

constructor( bytes  memory _jobId) {
    jobId = _jobId;
}
```